# Binding to a different ElementName on Windows 10 UWP using StateTriggers

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp, windows-10-universal, flyout

I have a `Flyout` with a helper to help bind to a Parent Element which determine its `PlacementTarget` property.

The line that I am trying to adjust is

```
helpers:FlyoutHelper.Parent="{Binding ElementName=appBarDelete}"
```

It works fine on Desktop but on Windows Mobile, I want to bind to a different `ElementName`. Is there a way to create something like conditional binding depending on whether it run on Mobile or Desktop?

I've tried binding to a string property in my ViewModel but the helper complains as it expects a FrameworkElement. I thought `ElementName` can be any string and perhaps there's an internal converter that convert this string to its `FrameworkElement`?

Any ideas?

```xml
<AppBarButton x:Name="menuZoom" Label="Thumbnail Size" >
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout x:Name="flyOut" helpers:FlyoutHelper.IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" helpers:FlyoutHelper.Parent="{Binding ElementName=appBarDelete}">
            <StackPanel Width="240">
                <TextBlock Text="Desired Size"/>
                <Slider Minimum="50" Maximum="500" Value="{Binding ImageDesiredWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Button Content="OK" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

Here's my `FloutHelper` class

```cs
public static class FlyoutHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVisibleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(FlyoutHelper),
        new PropertyMetadata(true, IsOpenChangedCallback));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Parent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(FlyoutHelper), null);

    public static void SetIsOpen(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsOpen(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsVisibleProperty);
    }

    private static async void IsOpenChangedCallback(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fb = d as FlyoutBase;
        if (fb == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            try
            {
                fb.Closed += flyout_Closed;
                fb.ShowAt(GetParent(d));
            }
            catch (Exception msg)
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog(msg.Message);
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            fb.Closed -= flyout_Closed;
            fb.Hide();
        }
    }

    private static void flyout_Closed(object sender, object e)
    {
        // When the flyout is closed, sets its IsOpen attached property to false.
        SetIsOpen(sender as DependencyObject, false);
    }

    public static void SetParent(DependencyObject element, FrameworkElement value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ParentProperty, value);
    }

    public static FrameworkElement GetParent(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (FrameworkElement)element.GetValue(ParentProperty);
    }
}
```

**Update**

I've managed to set the `Parent` property from the code behind using the following.

```
private void setFlyoutParent()
{
    if (DeviceTypeHelper.GetDeviceFormFactorType() == DeviceFormFactorType.Phone)
    {
        FlyoutHelper.SetParent(this.flyOut, this.appBarPath);
    }
    else
    {
        FlyoutHelper.SetParent(this.flyOut, this.appBarDelete);
    }
}
```

That works fine but I want to use the`VisualState.StateTriggers` and set the property on `MinWindowWidth`

Answer (score 0):

## AdaptiveTrigger

As you updated the question, it is also possible to use the `AdaptiveTrigger` to do what you need. Because the `FlyoutHelper.ParentProperty` is an attached property, you will need to use parentheses to set it like this:

```xml
<VisualState>
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <AdaptiveTrigger MaxWindowWidth="..." />
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="flyOut.(helpers:FlyoutHelper.Parent)" 
                Value="{Binding ElementName=theElementOnMobile}" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

## Alternative - in code

The easiest solution would be to do this in the code-behind of the page. In the constructor, after `InitializeComponent` call add the following:

```cs
if ( AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily.Contains( "Mobile" ) )
{
    flyOut.SetValue( FlyoutHelper.ParentProperty, theElementOnMobile );
}
else
{
    flyOut.SetValue( FlyoutHelper.ParentProperty, appBarDelete );
}
```

To make this cleaner, you can use the `DeviceUtils` provided by `Template 10` - [see on GitHub](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/af72162201820343e62e5cfd8309d9e288a30880/Template10%20(Library)/Utils/DeviceUtils.cs). With this, you can simplify the code to:

```cs
 flyOut.SetValue( FlyoutHelper.ParentProperty,
    DeviceUtils.CurrentDeviceFamily == DeviceFamilies.Mobile ?
       theElementOnMobile : appBarDelete );
```

Comment: Thanks @MZetko . I've figured out that's possible. However, I changed the question a little bit. I want to do it on `StateTriggers` . See the updated question. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but get an `DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION` with the message `Catastrophic failure`. I try creating a Public `Parent` property. `public FrameworkElement Parent
        {
            get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ParentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ParentProperty, value); }
        }` But VisualStudio complained `GetValue` and `SetValue` do not exist in the current context.

Comment: Perhaps I need to create a `UserControl` that inherits `Flyout`?

Comment: I think you need to add the namespace prefix to the Target - `helpers:FlyoutHelpers.Parent`. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Unforunately line `<Setter Target="flyOut.(helpers:FlyoutHelper.Parent)" Value="{Binding ElementName=appBarPath}" />` is marked with blue squiggle. On mouse hover it says `Catastrophic Failure (E_UNEXPECTED)`.  The app didn't crash but when the state is triggered, the Debug prints out `Exception thrown at 0x748296C2 (KernelBase.dll) in Textifier.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x800F1000, 0x00000055, 0x07FBDAE8).
onecoreuap\windows\dxaml\xcp\components\vsm\visualstatemanagerdatasource.cpp(259)\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll:  No installed components were detected`.